# Data not being returned from jQuery $.get in ASP.Net partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to get data from a web api using the jQuery `$.get` call, but the data is not being returned.  If I navigate to `uri` manually, I do show the data coming back in XML format with 4 nodes (Month1, Month2, Month3, Overall).  Am I not formatting this request correctly, or is something else going wrong?

```
$.get(uri, function (outputVal) {
        var parsedData = $.parseXML(outputVal);
        var monthArray = [parsedData. Month1Avail, parsedData.Month2Avail, parsedData.Month3Avail];
        var overall = parsedData.OverallAvailability;
    });
```

Here's the reply from `uri`:

```
<ExecutiveSummaryModels.AvailOutput xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/API.Models">
  <Month1Avail>99.977171779609279</Month1Avail>
  <Month2Avail>99.977303406084658</Month2Avail>
  <Month3Avail>99.977019739519733</Month3Avail>
  <OverallAvailability>99.93149492521367</OverallAvailability>
</ExecutiveSummaryModels.AvailOutput>
```

I'm calling the `$.get` from an ASP.Net partial view, if that matters.

Comment: What *does* come back from the server in this case?  When you debug, what's in `data`?  What's in `parsedData`?

Comment: It just says, "Data is not defined."  If I change the variable name to `outputVal` (just in case data is a reserved word??), it says, "outputVal is not defined."  Edit: the error I get in the console is that it can't read property 'Month1' of null

Comment: `data` is defined, but `Data` is not.  JavaScript is case sensitive.  What do you change to `outputVal`?  Where do you get an error saying it's not defined?  As for the `Month1` error... You're trying to read from a variable called `parsed`.  Where do you define *that* variable?  Pay attention to the names of your variables.  They can't be *close enough*, they have to be *exact*.

Comment: Good points.  I updated the code in the post to reflect the change to outputVal.  I was using the correct `data` variable name in the code, but had typed it incorrectly in the response.  Sorry about that.  I've also updated the variable name in the callback to `parsedData`, which, again, was correct in the implementation, just incorrect in the post.

Comment: Ok, so now what's the specific problem in the updated code?  When you debug, where does it fail?  What's the runtime value of `outputVal`?  Of `parsedData`?  If you're getting an error, what is the error and where does it happen?

Comment: `uri` is set just above the `$.get` as the address to the web api (`http://<address>/api/executivesummary/availability/<custNum>`).  If I go to the web api in a separate tab, it returns the XML values as shown in the post.  When I step through the code in debug, if I step over the `$.get` line, `outputVal` is not defined.  `parsedData` is not defined, as well.

Comment: `outputVal` and `parsedData` most certainly *are* defined in that callback function.  What do you mean by *"step over the `$.get` line"*?  Are you trying to access those variables *outside* of that function?  That certainly wouldn't work, since they only exist within that function's scope.  It's not clear where an actual error is happening here or what results you're expecting from a function that doesn't output anything.  Can you clarify specifically what indication of a problem exists?

Comment: When I say, _"Step over"_ I'm referring to the Step Over command in the debugger, meaning "just run it without stepping through every line".  I'm not looking to access the variables outside the function yet...just trying to get the values to load from the GET request right now.  The error I'm getting in the console if I run without debugging is, `Cannot read property 'Month1Avail' of null`.  So when the code is run, there is no value being passed into the `function (outputVal)`, and I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: Well, don't step over the function in debugging.  You're trying to figure out what's happening inside that function, so debug inside that function.  Put the breakpoint inside the function on the very first line.  Then you can examine what's in `data`.  That seems to be an important key here, and it's worth examining instead of assuming.

Comment: Excellent.  I found that the `$.parseXML` was unnecessary, and that `outputVal` held the values after entering the callback.  So `outputVal.Month1Avail` was the correct value.  Parsing was just messing it up.  I'll use this information and mark this as answered.  Thank you very much for your help, @David.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @David for helping me come to the answer.  The issue is that the `$.parseXML` line is unnecessary, and was cauing the `parsedData` variable to become null, which then couldn't subsequently be read.  Removing `$.parseXML` and changing the variable references to `outputVal` solved the issue.